# Rendering API data inside tab

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I've created a page with tabs and I want to display data from different API end point. I've created a tab and am trying to render the data in to the respective tab. I am using hooks to achieve this. With the help of the community members I've created a tab and navigating the tab to the correct index position. Now I am trying to render the respective API data into respective tab. If I set the state inside useEffect along with dependency I can see that values continuously hitting the DOM tree. Could anyone guide me how to populate the data to the respective tab from respective end point. Thanks in advance.

My end points are : https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1, https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2, https://reqres.in/api/users?page=3

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box p={3}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

const Tabb = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [prfData, setPrfData] = useState({});

  console.log("Page", page);

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=${page}`;
    console.log("URL", url);

    fetch(url)
      .then((results) => results.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log("response", resp);
        // setPage({ page: data.data });
        // setPage(resp.data);
        setPrfData(resp.prfData);
        setPage(resp.data);
      });
  }, [page, prfData]);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    console.log("new", newValue);
    setPage(newValue);
  };

  function a11yProps(index) {
    return {
      id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
      "aria-controls": `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
    };
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ marginLeft: "40%" }}>
      <h2>Tbas in React JS</h2>

      <Paper square>
        <Tabs
          textColor="primary"
          indicatorColor="primary"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={page}
        >
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)}></Tab>
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
        {/* <h3>Tab NO: {value} clicked!</h3> */}
        <TabPanel value={page} index={0}>
          <span>{JSON.stringify(prfData)}</span>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={page} index={1}>
          Item Two
        </TabPanel>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tabb;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've made a couple dependency loops in your `useEffect` hook. If you notice, you have a dependency on `page` in your useEffect and you're also calling `setPage` within that hook. The hook runs every time `page` changes, and since `setPage` changes `page` in the hook, it creates an infinite loop. This is also true for prfData where you depend on it and also call setPrfData.

Without knowing your exact needs for the application, I'll make the assumption that you probably don't need to be setting page to `data` within your hook and probably don't need a dependency on `prfData`. Removing those two things, the code looks like this:

```js
// ...
console.log("Page", page);

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=${page}`;
    console.log("URL", url);

    fetch(url)
      .then((results) => results.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log("response", resp);
        // setPage({ page: data.data });
        // setPage(resp.data);
        setPrfData(resp.prfData);
      });
  }, [page]);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
// ...
```